# str.replace not working to recode part of a string - no errors, but doesn't replace

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I have a pd df that I think I have converted to string and am certain I have converted to lowercase.

```
 raw_corpus['constructed_recipe'] = raw_corpus.constructed_recipe.astype('str')
 raw_corpus.loc[:,'constructed_recipe']=raw_corpus.constructed_recipe.apply(lambda x : str.lower(x))
display(raw_corpus)
```

I have tried the following two approaches to recode some of the strings:

```
raw_corpus.loc[:,'constructed_recipe']=raw_corpus.constructed_recipe.str.replace('to-dos ', 'to-do ')
```

and

```
raw_corpus.loc[:,'constructed_recipe']=raw_corpus['constructed_recipe'].str.replace('todos ','to-dos ')
```

Neither of these approaches produces an error, but they also don't recode. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this another example of the view vs copy issue that will surely be the death of me? If so, what is the fix?

Comment: Why the trailing space in replace string? 
You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: @StephenRauch trailing space is necessary so I only replace the string if it's not inside another string. otherwise, two words in the string could run together.

Comment: Okay, in the process of creating the example as @StephenRauch suggested, I discovered that both approaches work just fine! However, what seems to be happening if that I go back earlier in the program and run something else again, then run the subsequent replace code, the recode doesn't stick. I don't know enough python to understand why something that worked would become undone. Any pointers to anything I could read about this would be most appreciated.

Comment: One of the main reasons we ask for an MCVE is that in the process of creating one you can often answer your own question.  But in addition it makes it much easier to help.  So please continue creating an MCVE, and edit you post when you have one.

Comment: Run display(raw_corpus) again to see the changes. You just execute the code to replace the words but forgot to view it again. I was able to simulate and follow your problem.

Comment: @anonyXmous yes, that's it. MCVE is fair request.

Comment: Yup, we do this for free so the experts are very strict on MCVE.